# stripos PHP em LUA

Tags: php, lua

Quero converter este código PHP em linguagem LUA. O problema é que não existe a função `stripos` que conta a primeira ocorrência da palavra pretendida em LUA.

Como posso converter o código abaixo?

```
<?php
  echo stripos("I love php, I love php too!","PHP");
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para fazer a busca *case-insensitive*, pode-se usar a função [`string.lower()`](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial) para converter as letras para minusculas e procurar a primeira ocorrência com o [`string.find()`](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html).

```
function stripos (palheiro, agulha)
    palheiro = string.lower(palheiro)
    agulha = string.lower(agulha)

    if palheiro ~= nil and agulha ~= nil then   
        return (string.find(palheiro, agulha) -1)   
    else  
        return nil   
    end   
end

print(stripos("I love php, I love php too!", "PHP"))
```

[**`DEMO`**](http://ideone.com/TrOJfZ)